# Number of unique values grows slowly

Tags: probability

Let $X_i$ be iid rvs taking values in some countably infinite set $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \ldots\}$.

Let $D_n$ denote the number of unique values in the first $n$ variables. Show that $\frac{D_{n}}{n} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

I can show that (as well as an answer below) $E(\frac{D_{n}}{n}) \to 0$, but unless I am missing something, this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, pick a finite subset $S\subset \Omega$ with $P(X\in S)>1-\epsilon$. Then $E[D_n]\le |S|+n\epsilon$. So for $n >|S|/\epsilon$, $E[D_n]<2n\epsilon$, hence $E[D_n/n]\to0$. Conclude.